# Turning encrypted system on remotely

Tags: debian, remote, luks

My system is full of very sensitive data, so I need to encrypt as much of it as possible.

I have an encrypted Debian installation which asks for a long password every time during boot.
Is there a simple way to set it up so that I can input that password remotely?

If some other distribution can do it, I don't mind installing something else instead of Debian.

Comment: What kind of attack vector are you worried about? Is a hardware key store (where the private key can't be extracted by software, but anyone possessing that piece of hardware could decrypt your content) appropriate? (BTW, note that many full-disk encryption systems unlock a master key when you engage them, and then store that key in RAM -- meaning anyone with sufficient privileges can potentially copy that master key out from the unlocked system, even if they don't ever get your password; this is a place where having the actual decryption happen in hardware can be safer).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Main concern is server(or its disks) being physically stolen, so hardware key is out of the question, since it can be stolen as well. I specifically set 40+ symbol file system passphrase and 20+ symbol root password(who is the only user in the whole system), so I should be safe in most cases, right?

Comment: Removed and stolen, or are you worried about an attacker getting physical access while the hardware is still powered up? If someone can hotplug new devices onto the PCI bus they can make a copy of physical memory, so they can steal the encryption key out of a running, unlocked system. (They can't steal the password used to encrypt the key, but if you have the key itself, that's irrelevant).

Comment: Another attack vector is for someone to modify the boot sequence to make a copy of the password during the decrypt/unlock process, reboot your machine, and then wait for you to log in and unlock it (thus letting the code they added store a copy of the password out-of-band) before stealing the hardware. Coming up with comprehensive threat models (and mitigating against them) gets tricky sometimes. (I see madscientist159 already pointed that possibility out).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can enable this by installing [`dropbear-initramfs`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/dropbear-initramfs) and following [the instructions](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/dropbear.git/tree/debian/README.initramfs) to configure your SSH keys. This will start an SSH server from the initramfs, allowing you to connect remotely and enter your encryption passphrase.

Comment: Be aware that anyone with physical access to the machine can replace your initramfs with their own, malicious version, extract your SSH private key for a MITM attack, and various other forms of nastiness.  At minimum you should be looking at a TPM, if not more advanced security technology, if there is any chance of the box being physically accessed by a malicious actor.

Comment: @madscientist159 This is an acceptable risk, because full disk encryption is needed to protect from data leaking as a result of theft. Not physical presence attacks.
This is not a replacement for tamper protection (ex TPM).

Comment: @madscientist159 how would an attacker be able to extract my SSH private key if only the public key needs to be stored on the machine? What am I missing?

Comment: @andz that was probably a reference to the server’s private key — with that, an attacker could impersonate the server.

Comment: @StephenKitt I see, that makes sense. Thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed Debian on a Dell or HP server - Dell has iDrac and HP has ILO, both of these have web based virtual consoles which would allow you interact with the machine while booting.

Comment: My HP is too old to have ILO unfortunately, thanks for suggestion though.